# Bitnami LAMP composer Syntax errror, in Installer.php unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'

Tags: php, symfony, syntax, composer-php, bitnami

Bitnami Lampstack lampstack-5.6.18-0;

Composer version 1.0-dev;
Symfony 2.8.*.

running `cmd: composer require package` gives

```
Syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/oem/lampstack-5.6.18-0/sym_prog/pRec160224_28/vendor/ocramius/package-versions/src/PackageVersions/Installer.php on line 98.
```

Correcting the error in Installer.php does not help, because each time i run `composer require package`, the file is overwritten and the same error pop-outs.

What can be done? To reinstall composer in Bitnami Lapstack? To recreate Symfony project?

Comment: Can you please add in your question the full composer commands you used so we can try?

Answer (score 4):

Line 98 of `PackageVersions\Installer` has..

```
private static function generateVersionsClass(Composer $composer) : string
```

The `: string` is a return type that has been added as a feature of PHP7 which your version `5.6` doesn't recognise.

Your options are to upgrade to PHP7, not use `PackageVersions` or fork the repository, remove the return types and use that in your composer.json.

All of that being said, I'm not sure why composer is letting you install it as it has `PHP7` in it requirements. Maybe you have `config.platform.php` set incorrectly.

Comment: The "config.platform.php" does not exists in my file system. I was using: `sudo find / -iname config.platform.php > /home/oem/answ.txt ` to find it. Actually in order to run php i have to launch it from Bitnami Lamp executable console. Php does not exists in system at all. ALso composer was installed together with Bitnami LAMP. It works only from LAMP console. Which composer version is working?

Comment: `config.platform.php` is a composer variable that allows you to fake platform packages, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform .

Comment: Yes, i use composer require "package name". How to downgrade composer? I tried to use `composer  self-updade --version=1.0.0-alpha10`, which is version which was working for me from the May. But this does not work.

Comment: What php version were you running previously?

Comment: I was running different php versions: starting from 5.4.* up to 5.6.8. Never 7.*.*

Comment: Actually could you please give an example how to set this composer.platform.php variable ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the platform lines from composer.json :

```
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin" //remove the comma ,
//remove     "platform": {
//remove         "php": "5.3.9"
//remove    } 
    },
```

, If you can suggest other solutions, please let me to know.

Comment: So `config.platform.php`... I'm sorry that I didn't explain it better but that was the parameter I was talking about.